# Dedekind-MacNeille completion is a complete lattice

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathscr{P}$ be a poset and $DM(\mathscr{P}) = \{ A \subseteq \mathscr{P} | A = A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}} \}$. Here $x \in A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$ if and only if it is a lower bound of all upper bounds of $A$.
Then $DM(\mathscr{P})$ is a complete lattice. But how to finish the following proof?

Minimum element of $DM(\mathscr{P})$ is $\emptyset^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$.
(Why? Because $\emptyset^{\mathscr{u}} = \mathscr{P}$ and $\mathscr{P}^{\mathscr{l}} = \bot$?)

Let $\mathcal{A} = \{ A_i | i \in I \} \subseteq DM(\mathscr{P})$. So $\mathcal{A}$ consists of sets $A_i$ so that $A_i = A_i^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$ and $A_i \subseteq \mathscr{P}$.
And let $A = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i$.

Lets show that for every $\mathcal{A} \subseteq DM(\mathscr{P})$ there exists $\bigvee \mathcal{A}$ $(=A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}})$.

Now $A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}} \in DM(\mathscr{P})$ and $A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$ is an upper bound of $\mathcal{A}$. (How to prove these?)

Consider a subset $B \in DM(\mathscr{P})$ that is also an upper bound of $\mathcal{A}$, so $A \subseteq B$. Then $B^{\mathscr{u}} \subseteq A^{\mathscr{u}}$ and $A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}} \subseteq B^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$. Hence $A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$ is the least upper bound of $DM(\mathscr{P})$.
Therefore for every $\mathcal{A} \subseteq DM(\mathscr{P})$ there exists $\bigvee \mathcal{A}$
and so $DM(\mathscr{P})$ is a complete lattice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $\varnothing^{\text{ul}}$ is the minimum element of $DM(\mathscr{P})$, but there are two possibilities. If $\mathscr{P}$ has a minimum element $0$, then $\varnothing^{\text{u}}=\mathscr{P}$ and $\varnothing^{\text{ul}}=\{0\}$; if not, $\varnothing^{\text{u}}$ is still $\mathscr{P}$, but $\varnothing^{\text{ul}}=\varnothing$. In either case $\varnothing^{\text{ul}}$ is clearly a subset of every element of $DM(\mathscr{P})$.

Now let $A=\bigcup_{i\in I}A_i$, where each $A_i\in DM(\mathscr{P})$. For each $i\in I$ we have $A_i\subseteq A$, so $A_i^{\text{u}}\supseteq A^{\text{u}}$, and therefore $A_i=A_i^{\text{ul}}\subseteq A^{\text{ul}}$, so $A^{\text{ul}}$ is an upper bound for $\mathscr{A}=\{A_i:i\in I\}$.

Comment: Clearly $A = \bigcup_{i \in I} A_i \subseteq \mathscr{P}$ and $A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}} \subseteq \mathscr{P}$. But in order to get $A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}} \in DM(\mathscr{P})$, shouldn't it also be proven that $A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}=(A^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}})^{\mathscr{u}\mathscr{l}}$?

Comment: @onm: That’s a general fact: $\cdot^{\text{ul}}$ is a closure operator and hence idempotent. For any $A$ we have $A\subseteq A^{\text{ul}}$, so $A^{\text{u}}\supseteq A^{\text{ulu}}$. But for any $A$ we also have $A\subseteq A^{\text{lu}}$, and applying this to $A^{\text{u}}$ yields $A^{\text{u}}\subseteq A^{\text{ulu}}$, so in fact $A^{\text{u}}=A^{\text{ulu}}$, and therefore $A^{\text{ul}}=A^{\text{ulul}}$.